# How to convert String to java.util.date so as to make it insertable to the mysql database column of type "DATE"?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, date-parsing

The user inputs a date as a `string`, but I need to make that insertable to the database column of datatype `DATE`. This is how I've defined my `startDate` variable in my `Event.java` class:

```
@Column(name = "start_date")
@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
private Date startDate;
```

> **Note:** The `Date` datatype is from the class `java.util.Date`

The user inputs the date like this:
[image: Date Input]

I fetch that data as a string value with the following bit of code in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addEvent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addEvent(
            //OTHER PARAMETERS
            @RequestParam("startDate") String startDate,
            //OTHER PARAMETERS
                              ) {

        //CODE TO MAP EVENT DATA TO THE ENTITY CLASS
        eventDAO.insert(event);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

The above code successfully inserts an event to the database but leaves the `start_date` column `NULL`. How do I parse the string value to a `date` datatype so as to be insertable into the MySQL DB?

**EDIT:**

I tried adding the following to parse it but it still inserts `NULL`.

```
        Date finalStartDate=null;
        String startDateParser = startDate;
        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        try{
        finalStartDate = format.parse(startDateParser);
        System.out.println(finalStartDate);
        } catch(ParseException ex){
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

        Event event = new Event();
        //MAPPING OTHER DATA
        event.setStartDate(finalStartDate);
```

I got this message in my server:

```
Unparseable date: "2018-04-19"
```

Comment: Use either DateFormat or, better yet, the new java.time package.

Comment: @duffymo I think you mean DateFormat.

Comment: @duffymo Thanks, I'll try that

Comment: Either a Google or SO search will turn up more examples than you can shake a stick at.  You can't be a developer without using the internet to find such resources.

Comment: Please check this question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion

Comment: @turing042 have you check event object in your controller method?First need to find out if the `startDate` have value

Comment: @gil.fernandes thanks for the link, I tried that but got some error, so I've added a few more lines to my original post accordingly.

Comment: @turing042 Please check the answer below.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll definitely check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specific error in this case is the wrong date format. Instead of `MM/dd/yyyy` you should use `yyyy-MM-dd` in order to parse the date.

If the date cannot be parsed `null` is inserted in the database and that is ok. This means that the format of the date is wrong.

Here is a snippet of code which should work be able to parse the date:

```
String startDateParser = "2018-04-19";
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date finalStartDate = null;
try {
    finalStartDate = format.parse(startDateParser);
    System.out.println(finalStartDate);
} catch (ParseException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: The format used to input the date in the browser and internal processing is different I suppose. Anyway, this worked, thanks Gil!